# escape double quotes in url of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call as

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url&para1=' + JSON.stringify(obj),
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
    },
    error: function(error){

    }
});
```

In the url i get `%22` for every `"`

How can that be escaped?

Comment: You are sending your `json` data in URL query string and sending `data:{}` in a `type: "POST"`, oh boy, I think there are far more optimization options than just escaping the `"`. Try a different approach, use `data` for posting `POST` data. That would be the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help

```
url: 'url&para1=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)),
```

Answer (score 2):

%22 **is** the "escaped" value for a double quote. It's the accepted way to send that data in a URI. Where exactly are you running into a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON.stringify converts the object into a string. However, a string with quotes must be converted to a URL encoded string (see superrafal's answer).

However, if this is a POST request, why are you sending parameters in the URL as a query string (?key=value) like a GET request? The data parameter is set to a blank object. If you desire to send those values in the URL as a GET, change the type to GET, remove the "data" parameter, and use $.param(obj) to convert that object to a query string. If you desire to send those values as a POST, use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url_to_file_to_accept_POST_request",
    type: "POST",
    data: obj,
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(error) {

    }
});
```